# tabcontrol tabitem without borders and hyperlink like tabitem

Tags: wpf

How can I create tabitems that look like hyperlinks and user is unaware that tabcontrol is used, i.e. no borders on tabitems?  So it would like like horizontal menu bar (with no subitems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite the default [TabControl.Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx) to hide the borders, then just style your TabItem headers to look like hyperlinks.

Here's an example of overwriting the `TabControl.Template`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TabControl_NoHeadersTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- TabItem Headers -->
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />

        <!-- Selected Tab Content -->
        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then you can use just the following to apply the template:

```
<TabControl Template="{StaticResource TabControl_NoHeadersTemplate}" />
```

Comment: That's probably extremly complicated.  But I've found at least how to do a hyperlink:   <TabItem.Header>
                                <Hyperlink>Getting started</Hyperlink>
                            </TabItem.Header

Comment: @Nickolodeon It's not complicated at all. See the example I added to my answer

Comment: @Nickolodeon You think 7 lines of code and a copy/paste control template to restyle a TabControl to look completely different are extremely complicated ??!

Comment: Copy paste isn't.  But figuring out by self with zero knowledge means probably reading about 50 pages trying to tear out what will work, plus experiments.  Thanks alot for an example.

Comment: But what will make tabitems have no borders?  You probably didn't include it?

Comment: By the way.  What is the difference betweeen template and style?  Couldn't I just put <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControl_NoHeadersTemplate}" />?

Comment: @Nickolodeon The `Template` is how WPF draws the `TabControl`. By overwriting the default template, you are drawing the `TabControl` as a DockPanel with a StackPanel, with no borders (see the link in my answer to view the default TabControl `Template`). You can set the `Style` instead of the `Template`, however then you need to set the `Template` property in your `Style`